# Jest: ReferenceError: Request is not defined

Tags: api, request, jestjs, referenceerror

I can't get my jest test to pass even though the code works:

```
describe("Testing the API call", () => {
  test("Testing the API call", () => {
    sendToServer("Hey there!")
  })
})
```

And jest throws me this: 
[ReferenceError: Request is not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OPqy.jpg) (it can't find Request constructor)

I'm pretty new to jest so I have only tried what I could find on stack overflow, but there are no solutions to this one. I tried to import Request from html and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to help you if you would share your `getData` function, but let me assume that you are doing something like, for fetching your data:

```
async function getUsers() {
  const URL = `https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10`;
  try {
    const response = await fetch(URL);
    return response.json();
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return {}
  }
}
```

The above function will make a call to the [Random User API](https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10) and return an Object with an array of results, in our case 10 random users.

In order to test this function, you can write tests, such as:

```
  describe('getUsers function', () => {
    test('the data returned is an object', async () => {
     const data = await index.getUsers();
     expect(data).toBeInstanceOf(Object);
  });
    test('the Results array has 10 entries', async () => {
      const data = await index.getUsers();
      expect(data.results.length).toBe(10)
    });
  });
```

Here you will assert, that you do return Object from the call and that you do return correct number of users on call.

Comment: Ok. I tried this one before but it caused another error:
`regeneratorRuntime is not defined`

however I solved it by:
`import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";`
into the file that was exporting the function and I
also added one more requirement to server just in case